# extract zip files using python

Tags: python, file, extract, zip

```
import zipfile

fantasy_zip = zipfile.ZipFile('E:\\Shared\\DOWNLOADED\\c.zip')
fantasy_zip.extractall('E:\\Shared\\DOWNLOADED\\extract)

fantasy_zip.close()
```

my password is "hello"
how can I include password to extract?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Python `zipfile` package can unzip files having password.

```
def unzip_folder(zip_folder, destination, pwd):
        """
        Args:
            zip_folder (string): zip folder to be unzipped
            destination (string): path of destination folder
            pwd(string): zip folder password

        """
        with zipfile.ZipFile(zip_folder) as zf:
            zf.extractall(
                destination, pwd=pwd.encode())
```

In your case,

```
import zipfile
zip_folder = 'E:\\Shared\\DOWNLOADED\\c.zip'
destination = 'E:\\Shared\\DOWNLOADED'
pwd = '<YOUR_PASSWORD>'

with zipfile.ZipFile(zip_folder) as zf:
    zf.extractall(
        destination, pwd=pwd.encode())
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, based on the error I got, invalid syntax in line number 1

Comment: I don't get it.Line number. 1 in your syntax or in mine?

Comment: def unzip_folder("E:\\Shared\\DOWNLOADED\\c.zip", "E:\\Shared\\DOWNLOADED\\extract", "virus"):
        """
        Args:
            zip_folder (string): zip folder to be unzipped
            destination (string): path of destination folder
            pwd(string): zip folder password

        """
        with zipfile.ZipFile(zip_folder) as zf:
            zf.extractall(
                destination, pwd=pwd.encode())

Comment: this is the error:   File "E:\Shared\DOWNLOADED\sample.py", line 1
    def unzip_folder("E:\\Shared\\DOWNLOADED\\c.zip", "E:\\Shared\\DOWNLOADED\\extract", "virus"):
                                                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Why there are values in quote (" ") in your function definition?

Comment: should I remove all the double quotes?

Comment: I have edited my answer above. For your case, you can simply define variables for those arguments and call unzip.

Comment: File "C:\Python27\lib\zipfile.py", line 1040, in extractall
    self.extract(zipinfo, path, pwd)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\zipfile.py", line 1028, in extract
    return self._extract_member(member, path, pwd)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\zipfile.py", line 1082, in _extract_member
    with self.open(member, pwd=pwd) as source, \
  File "C:\Python27\lib\zipfile.py", line 1007, in open
    raise RuntimeError("Bad password for file", name)
RuntimeError: ('Bad password for file', <zipfile.ZipInfo object at 0x03277850>)

Comment: You have set wrong password. Do you know the password of the zipfile? It is clear in your error message.

Comment: I am glad it helps you out.

Answer (score 0):

```
from zipfile import ZipFile

with ZipFile('E:\Shared\DOWNLOADED\c.zip') as fileobj:
    fileobj.extractall(pwd='hello')
```

> Take care, python3's zipfile only supports encrypted zip files that
>   use CRC-32 based encryption This seems to be the default for the "zip"
>   program on linux, but this doesn't work for AES encryption, or for
>   many Windows based zip solutions See
>   https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/Lib/zipfile.py for more
>   details

Comment: Thank you for the help, based on https://docs.python.org/2/library/zipfile.html the codes works when I am using a zip file without password.